# Is using local variable instead of instance variable improve the performance(save memory) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, instance

I have created Rails application and I have used lots of instance variables and most of them are not required in the views. Do I need to replace the unused instance variables for improving the performance?

Sample code:

```
def show

custom_fields_data = fetch_custom_field_data

@selected_custom_fields_opt_from_view = []
if custom_fields_data.present?
  @listings = @listing.category.listings.where("price_cents!=? AND open= ?",0,true).reject { |l| l.author.main_admin? }

  @selected_custom_fields_opt_from_view = custom_fields_data.map do |custom_field_data|
    CustomField.find(custom_field_data[0]).options.find(custom_field_data[1])
  end


  @listings.each do |listing|

    # array to store the selected  a custom field's option from Database
    selected_custom_fields_opt_from_db = []

    listing.custom_field_values.each do |custom_field_value|
      selected_custom_fields_opt_from_db.push(custom_field_value.selected_options.first)
    end
    if selected_custom_fields_opt_from_db.uniq.sort == @selected_custom_fields_opt_from_view.uniq.sort || (@selected_custom_fields_opt_from_view - selected_custom_fields_opt_from_db).empty?
      similar_listing.push(listing)
    end
  end

  @listings = similar_listing

end


@listing_with_filters = similar_listing.present? ? @listings.first : @listing

@selected_tribe_navi_tab = "home"
unless current_user?(@listing.author)
  @listing.increment!(:times_viewed)
end

@current_image = if params[:image]
                   @listing.image_by_id(params[:image])
                 else
                   @listing.listing_images.first
                 end

@prev_image_id, @next_image_id = if @current_image
                                   @listing.prev_and_next_image_ids_by_id(@current_image.id)
                                 else
                                   [nil, nil]
                                 end

payment_gateway = MarketplaceService::Community::Query.payment_type(@current_community.id)
process = get_transaction_process(community_id: @current_community.id, transaction_process_id: @listing.transaction_process_id)
form_path = new_transaction_path(listing_id: @listing.id)

delivery_opts = delivery_config(@listing.require_shipping_address, @listing.pickup_enabled, @listing.shipping_price, @listing.shipping_price_additional, @listing.currency)

@category = @listing.category
@template_listing = @category.template_listing
if @current_user
  # For Pivot table
  @selected_custom_field = params[:custom_field] if params[:custom_field]
  @listing_for_pivot = Listing.new
  @listing_images = @listing.listing_images
  @shape = get_shape(@listing.listing_shape_id)
  @unit_options = ListingViewUtils.unit_options(@shape[:units], unit_from_listing(@template_listing)).first if @shape
  @custom_field_questions = @category.custom_fields
  @numeric_field_ids = numeric_field_ids(@custom_field_questions)
  @category_tree = CategoryViewUtils.category_tree(
      categories: ListingService::API::Api.categories.get(community_id: @current_community.id)[:data],
      shapes: get_shapes,
      locale: I18n.locale,
      all_locales: @current_community.locales
  )
  if @template_listing.present?
    @listing_for_pivot.title = @template_listing.title
    @listing_for_pivot.description = @template_listing.description
    @listing_images = @template_listing.listing_images if @template_listing.listing_images.present?
    @listing_for_pivot.listing_shape_id = @template_listing.listing_shape_id
  end
  if (@current_user.location != nil)
    temp = @current_user.location
    temp.location_type = "origin_loc"
    @listing_for_pivot.build_origin_loc(temp.attributes)
  else
    @listing_for_pivot.build_origin_loc(:location_type => "origin_loc")
  end
  @custom_field_area = CategoryCustomField.where(category_id: @category.id, custom_field_id: @category.custom_fields.pluck(:id))

  @row = @category.custom_field_row
  @row = @custom_field_area.first.custom_field if @row.nil? && @custom_field_area.first

  @column = @category.custom_field_column
  @column = @custom_field_area.second.custom_field if @column.nil? && @custom_field_area.second

  @filters = @category.custom_field_filters
  @filters = @custom_field_area.all.from(1).map { |category_custom_field| category_custom_field.custom_field } if @filters.nil? && @custom_field_area.size > 2


  @selected_value_for_filter = []
  if @filters.present?
    if @selected_custom_field
      @filters.each do |filter|
        if (@selected_custom_field["#{filter.id.to_s}_"])
          @selected_value_for_filter.push(filter.options.find(@selected_custom_field["#{filter.id.to_s}_"]))
        else
          @selected_value_for_filter.push(filter.options.first)
        end
      end
    else
      @filters.each do |filter|
        @selected_value_for_filter.push(filter.options.first)
      end
    end
  end
  # Pivot table section end
end

@applicant = @category.listings.pluck(:author_id).uniq
@suggested_business_accounts = @category.people.where("people.id NOT IN (?)", @applicant);
if @suggested_business_accounts.present?
  @business_locations =
      @suggested_business_accounts.map do |person|
        person.location
      end
  @business_locations.compact!
end

render locals: {
    form_path: form_path,
    payment_gateway: payment_gateway,
    # TODO I guess we should not need to know the process in order to show the listing
    process: process,
    delivery_opts: delivery_opts,
    listing_unit_type: @listing.unit_type
}
end
```

Comment: can you insert your code for easy looking to your issues?

Comment: @Walfie : I have added the sample code.

Comment: thanks. It'll be easier for answerer to understand your problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use instance variables if you don't want to send them to views. The scope of the variables should be narrowest, therefore in your case if you are not using instance variables in the views you should convert them to local.

Answer (score 0):

Using instance variables instead of local variables is a bad idea at least memory-wise.

Instance variable exists while the object that holds it exists. On the contrary, local variable exists only inside method/block it is defined.

Garbage collector does not care whether you use instance variable elsewhere beyond the method or not.

Thus, if you have instance variables, which you only intend to use within the method - change them to local ones.